# JS Calculate distance from centre of viewport

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to centre an image with absolute position when hovering. 
but since the image is nested within multiple divs, top and left distances are not ideal.

How can I change the script so that it refers to the centre of the viewport instead?

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("#image").css({
    left: e.clientX,
    top: e.clientY
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try using `document.body.clientWidth / 2` and `document.body.clientHeight / 2`?

Comment: @IshantSolanki not really. how would the script become?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but a possible solution can be in the lines of

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("#image").css({
    left: document.body.clientWidth / 2,
    top: document.body.clientHeight / 2
  });
});
```

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't seem to work as it doesn't follow the cursor

Comment: the script on top is meant to make the image appearing at hover following the cursor. what it fails to do is indeed calculate the right distances for the image to be centred.

you can find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Mengolor/2wzv6tr1/1/

Comment: From the fiddle i can see that it manages to move along the cursor but below it. Do you want to move the image position to center of the cursor?

Comment: Yes, the desired effect is indeed to always have the image centred to the cursor (despite the scrolling position).